# How to read web.config appsetting key value in Type Script of Service Class

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I am developing angular 2 application using visual studio 2015, In my current project I want to get the app setting value from web.config in typescript file(service.ts)

Before posting this question into this, I did google it and read some links but I did not get it. This is the link I read earlier but I did not get a result: https://forums.asp.net/t/2071477.aspx?How+to+read+web+config+appsetting+key+value+in+Type+Script

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access web.config appsettings from Angular js 2 Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489598/access-web-config-appsettings-from-angular-js-2-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a web.config file directly from TypeScript. You have to write it into your html document first with some type of ServerSide code. You can store the setting either in a hidden html text field or inside a javascript variable. Then you can read that text field or javascript variable in Typescript.

This has been answered before here: [Reading web.config from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910095/reading-web-config-from-javascript)

Comment: I don't know how to write the code, please tell me or ping example code here.

Answer (score 0):

As any xml file you can do something like :

```
        let url : string = path_to_your_file;
        let observableResult: Observable<any>
            = this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.text())
            .subscribe((xml : any) => {
              let parser = new DOMParser();
              let webConfig= parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
              let nodes = webConfig.getElementsByTagName('add');

              for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                     parse_property(nodes.item(i));
              }, ...)
         }
```

Comment: I am new to Type Script. So, Please mention the complete code for how to parse the web.config file using typescript.

Comment: Web.config is just an xml file. This code is nearly ready to use. The difficulty is to expose your web.config via http. Maybe you will prefer a solution like Remy's. And the "parse_property" function depends on your own application... You may just replace it by a `console.log` to see a result...

Comment: I copied above code and past it in my typescript file where ever I want. but I gave the path to my web.config file like this "./web.config" . is this correct path to my web.config file or not. and also observableResult variable shows error like "Type subscription is not assigned to type observable<any>".